# I try to use IN in mysql 'CASE WHEN' condition

Tags: mysql, sql, case, conditional-statements

Hi I have problems trying to reach the value of 3 because my query does not recognize the selection of two countries using the clause 'IN'

a) This is my simple table source:

**id    | country**

1     | CL

2   | BR

b) this is my sql query:

```
SELECT
(
CASE 
    WHEN country ='CL' THEN 1
    WHEN country = 'BR' THEN 2
    WHEN country IN ('BR','CL') THEN 3
    ELSE 0
END) AS result 
FROM countries 
WHERE country IN ('BR','CL') ;
```

c) This is the current output result:

**Result**

1

2

Comment: I don't understand the logic. In a `case` statement the order of conditions matter. If the first condition is met it does not move on to the next. So your query is working how it is supposed to.

Comment: To mirror the comment by @JChao your third WHEN and ELSE conditions make no sense at all as they are unreachable.  You could in fact simplify the whole thing to `CASE WHEN country = 'CL' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END` since you are already filtering results to BR and CL values in your WHERE clause.

Comment: D) What is the desired result?

Comment: i need an logic, that allow me the possibility of reaching the three  Possibilities under the selection of two countries
first when I select CL, when I select BR, and finally when I select the two.

Comment: the desired result is 3

Comment: IN third case I guess you need AND not IN which acts like OR

Comment: the case expression will be executed for every row separately and you don't have any rows containing more than one country. also you can't get 3!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you want something like the following:

```
SELECT CASE 
          WHEN cntAll = 2 THEN 3
          WHEN cntCL >= 1 THEN 1
          WHEN cntBR >= 1 THEN 2
          ELSE 0           
       END AS result
FROM (
  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT country) AS cntAll,
         COUNT(CASE WHEN country = 'CL' THEN 1 END) AS cntCL,
         COUNT(CASE WHEN country = 'BR' THEN 1 END) AS cntBR
  FROM countries
  WHERE country IN ('CL', 'BR')) AS t
```

When *both* `('CL', 'BR')` values are present in `countries` table, then output is `3`, otherwise if only `'CL'` is present output is `1`, otherwise if only `'BR'` is present output is `2`, otherwise output is `0`.

Answer (score 0):

The [CASE ... END expression](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case) uses shortcut evaluation:

> ```
> CASE value WHEN [compare_value] THEN result [WHEN [compare_value] THEN result ...] [ELSE result] END
>
> CASE WHEN [condition] THEN result [WHEN [condition] THEN result ...] [ELSE result] END
> ```
>
> The first version returns the result where value=compare_value. The
>   second version returns the result for the **first condition that is
>   true**. If there was no matching result value, the result after ELSE is
>   returned, or NULL if there is no ELSE part.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic in typing the query is not well designed!
First you need to concatenate the country field then put the case expression.

**select GROUP_CONCAT(country)  from countries**

You will get the following result "**BR,CL,...**"

Then you put the case expression like that:

select 
Case      when result like '%CL%' THEN 1

when result like '%BR%' THEN 2
     when result like '%BR%' and result like '%CL%' THEN 3
      else 0
from 
(select GROUP_CONCAT(country) as result  from countries)